# Easy way to create and initialise a 3D table of structs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

I would like to be able to initialise a big table in matlab easily.

Say I have the bounds x, y, z = 5, 4, 3. I want to be able to make a 5x4x3 table where each element is a struct that stores count and sum. Count and sum in this struct should be 0 when initialised.

I thought it would be enough to do this:

```
table = []
table(5,4,3) = struct('sum', 0, 'count', 0)
```

And this would work for a double but not with a structure evidently.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

As another question, (bonus if you will) is there a way to force matlab to store the struct, but when you access the element (i.e., table(1, 2, 3)) get it to return the average (i.e., table(1,2,3).sum/table(1,2,3).count).

Its not vital to the question but it would certainly be cool.

Comment: Please note that I edited my answer to address your second question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need just to replace the line `table = []` to avoid the error, that is

```
clear table;
table(5,4,3) = struct('sum', 0, 'count', 0)
```

works fine. Note, however, that this command only initializes one field of your array, i.e., the memory allocation is incomplete. To initialize all fields of your array, you can use

```
table2(1:5,1:4,1:3) = struct('sum', 0, 'count', 0)
```

to visualize the difference, use `whos`, which returns

```
>> whos
  Name        Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes  
  table       5x4x3              736  struct              
  table2      5x4x3             8288  struct
```

Your second question can be solved, for instance, by using anonymous functions

```
 myMean = @(a) a.sum./a.count; %define the function

 myMean(table2(2,2,2)) % access the mean in the field (2,2,2)
```